# Using a class not in current directory in a Groovy script

Tags: class, groovy, load, classpath

MyClass.groovy has

```
def static a(){ ... }
```

MyScript.groovy uses MyClass like:

```
x = MyClass.a()
```

This works fine if MyClass.groovy is in the same directory as MyScript.groovy. If I put MyClass.groovy in ~/.groovy/lib or another directory that is part of CLASSPATH it does not work. Is there another way to tell Groovy where to find MyClass.groovy if it is not in the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

With the command line in `groovy` we are automatically using a `GroovyClassLoader`, which is able to compile scripts on the fly.

If you have `MyClass.groovy` and `MyScript.groovy` in a classpath folder and they are not compiled yet, the `GroovyClassLoader` will compile them automatically. Since the current directory is part of the classpath, it is working when you have both files in the current directory.

So it should work as long as both files are included in the classpath.

Regarding `./groovy/lib`, you can make it work if you put there a `.jar` file with the `MyClass.class` or `MyClass.groovy` files in it. The `GROOVY_HOME/conf/groovy-starter.conf` controls what is loaded:

```
# load required librarieS
load !{groovy.home}/lib/*.jar

# load user specific libraries
load !{user.home}/.groovy/lib/*.jar

# tools.jar for ant tasks
load ${tools.jar}
```

So you can edit this configuration to add a path where you can put the scripts you want automatically loaded. For example,

```
# test
load !{user.home}/.groovy/myscripts/
```